# django rest framework Viewset for single item, not list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am having a problem with my DRF API. I want to provide a read only endpoint that takes a single id from a object(document) in the DB and runs a script to perform an check and gives back the result.
It works fine when I call the API with //api/documentcheck/1/ where 1 is the pk of the document in the DB.
The problem is that if I just call the base URL //api/documentcheck/ it tries to give back the results of all documents in the database and times out because it takes ages.

I am looking for a way to remove the list view and force users to provide the ID for a single document to check.

This is my serializer class

```
class DocumentCheckSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    '''Serializer for document check'''
 
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = '__all__'
 
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return process_document(value)
```

This is my view:

```
class DocumentCheck(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """Check a single document"""
    authentication_classes = (
    TokenAuthentication,
    SessionAuthentication,
    BasicAuthentication,
    )
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Document.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DocumentCheckSerializer
```

and my router entry

```
router.register("documentcheck", views.DocumentCheck, basename="documentcheck")
```

Comment: In your viewset, you can override `list` and return 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just `GenericViewSet` and `RetrieveModelMixin` as your base class

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet
from rest_framework.mixins import RetrieveModelMixin

class DocumentCheck(GenericViewSet, RetrieveModelMixin):
    """Check a single document"""
    authentication_classes = (
    TokenAuthentication,
    SessionAuthentication,
    BasicAuthentication,
    )
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Document.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.DocumentCheckSerializer
```